# What datatype can be used for array index 0 to 4000000 when i used int or unsigned long long my program crashes

Tags: c, arrays

For finding the even number of fibonnaci series

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[4000000];
    int sum=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4000000;i++)
    {
       if(i==0)
       {
           a[0]=1;
       }
       else if(i==1)
       {
           a[1]=2;
       }
       else
       {
           a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2];
       }
       if(a[i]%2==0)
       {
           sum+=a[i];
       }
    //printf("a[%d]=%d\n",i,a[i]);
    }
    printf("sum=%d\n",sum);//
    return 0;
}
```

This code crashes when i compile.But for a=10 this code works just fine.
I tried changing the type to unsigned long long and format specifier to %llu still the code crashes even when i changed the main datatype to unsigned long long it is not working i thought the number 4000000 is too big for int type but when i searched i got this code from other user in his website which is

```
// Simple Program to print Fibonacci series in Console
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x=1,y=2,sum=0,limit=0,i=0,temp=0;
    printf("Enter Limit:");
    scanf("%d",&limit);

    if(limit==1)
        printf("%d",x);
    else if(limit>1) {
        printf("%d %d",x,y);
        if (limit>2) {
            while (i<limit-2) {
                temp=y;
                sum=x+y;
                x=temp;
                y=sum;
                printf(" %d",sum);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }      
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

this code works just fine 
I am a beginner and a self taught i don't know what is wrong with my code is it because i used an array.Please help to rectify this.
Thank you.

Comment: It is probably too big for the stack. Better to allocate dynamic memory.

Comment: To compile is not to run. Your code crashes when you run it.

Comment: Stack size is typically 8 MiB on UNIX and smaller on Windows. You attempt to allocate close to 16 MiB; a crash ensues. Make the variable global, or use dynamic memory (`malloc()` et al).

Comment: Unrelated to the crash you observe, but to index arrays most often (the unsigned!) `size_t` would be the type of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Most implementations have a fairly small limit on the size of stack frames. If you need a large array, make it static or allocate it dynamically.

```
static int a[4000000];
```

Answer (score 1):

On most systems local variables are allocated on the stack. A stack has limited size so creating a huge array as a local variable will overflow the stack.

Instead use dynamic memory like:

```
int* a = malloc(4000000 * sizeof *a);
if (a == NULL)
{
    // no more memory
    exit(1);
}

// Now a can be used as an array, e.g. a[1234] = 42

... put your code here


// When done, deallocate memory like:
free(a);
```

That said - there is no point in using an array that huge. Simple integer types can't hold the values for that many Fibonacci numbers. There will be integer overflow in the calculations and your result will be wrong. You can check this by using `int a[100];` and then print the calculated values. You'll soon see that they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** (for some reasons) to use automatic storage variables - increase the stack size.

for example this way:

```
int SeStack(rlim_t size)
{
    struct rlimit rlim;
    if(!getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlim))
    {
        if (rlim.rlim_cur <= size)
        {
            rlim.rlim_cur = size;
            return setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlim);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return EPERM;
}
```